# Spring async method for different executors

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

Suppose I have more than one beans in my spring configuration all created from one class.

```
<bean id="beanInstance1" class="foo.BeanClass"/>
<bean id="beanInstance2" class="foo.BeanClass"/>
<bean id="beanInstance3" class="foo.BeanClass"/>

<task:executor id="executor1" pool-size="10"/>
<task:executor id="executor2" pool-size="10"/>
<task:executor id="executor3" pool-size="10"/>
```

I want to enable async execution of the method of that class but in a way that all beans had their own thread pool executor. How can I achieve that? Here's my simple class

```
public class BeanClass {

    @Async
    Future<Object> doSomeAsyncTask(Object data) {
        /* async task executed here */
        return new AsyncResult<>(null)
    }

}
```

Comment: You cannot do that with an annotation I'm afraid as that will only allow for a definition of a single executor (you could pass in the name into the `@Async` annotation).

Comment: @M.Deinum well, thats a bummer... Thanks anyway!

Comment: If this configuration is "a bit static", then you could declare BeanClass as abstract and create implementations that would only differ with value in @Async. Would not be pretty, but would do what you need. You could hide these classes in subpackage or smth.